# Android. Проверка версии приложения в Play Market

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. *Сразу же извиняюсь за возможную кривизну вопроса.*

Можно ли программно проверить версию приложения в Play Market, чтобы при появлении обновления, пользователи старой версии, через само приложение узнали бы о появления обновления?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вы как разработчик меняете версию в своем приложении и заливаете на Маркет. Маркет автоматом уведомляет старую версию, в данном случае, пользователя (устройство) со старой версией о наличии обновления.

Comment: автор наверно имеет ввиду если у юзеров отключены уведомления о новых версиях  например

Comment: @Сергей: насильно мил не будешь тогда

Answer (score 3):

Есть сторонняя библиотека AppUpdater: https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater

AppUpdater проверяет наличие обновлений на Google Play, GitHub, Amazon, F-Droid или вашем собственном сервере. Библиотека сообщает о наличии обновлений в вашем приложении при помощи диалога, Snackbar или уведомления.

Comment: Переведи на русский язык, так, как это русскоязычный ресурс.